# How to calculate dataframe row size as Mongo document to send as input for Mongo Spark Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I want to pass dataframe as an input for spark mongo connector. But I want to eliminate the records which is greater than `16 MB` size not to get the Maximum size exception from `Mongo DB`. Can anyone help me how efficiently I can filter the rows?

Note : I tried `SizeEstimator.estimate(row)`. I didn't work for me as the JVM size is different than Mongo Document size.

Help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/non/clouseau) library which may be helpful to you to calculate the row sizes in bytes. Once imported in my project, I calculated the row sizes in the following way:

Import the clouseau library, Spark SQL functions and Spark implicits:

```
import clouseau.Calculate
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
```

Create a user Defined Function so that it takes a `Row` object and returns its size.

```
val calculateRowSize = udf((row: Row) => Calculate.sizeOf(row))
```

Apply the User Define Function by passing all the columns, and remove those rows whose size is greater than 16 MB.

```
df
  .withColumn("rowSize", calculateRowSize(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)))
  .filter($"rowSize" <= 16000000)
```

Hope it's helpful.